# initWithCapacity: in NSArray

Tags: iphone

`initWithCapacity:` is declared in `NSMutableArray`, but I want to use it to initialize an `NSArray`. I there any solution?

Answer (score 12):

Since `NSArray` objects are immutable (cannot change the objects they contain) there's no use in adjusting the capacity of `NSArray`s.

The capacity is the number of objects an array can contain without reallocating memory. It is only used for optimization.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense to init an `NSArray` using `initWithCapacity:`, because you can't subsequently add objects. An `NSArray` with no objects in has a de facto capacity of 0. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: That question is completely unrelated to his answer.

Comment: I'm implementing a fix-sized cache and find that `NSArray` fits that criteria. Initializing an empty array with capacity does make sense, doesn't it?

Comment: That is, what NSMutableArray is for.

Answer (score 5):

Just make an `NSMutableArray` with `initWithCapacity:`, fill it with stuff, and then make an `NSArray` from it.

You can use either:

```
NSArray *_immutableArray = [_mutableArray copy];
...
[_immutableArray release];
```

Or:

```
NSArray *_immutableArray; 
[_immutableArray initWithArray:_mutableArray];
...
[_immutableArray release];
```

Or:

```
NSArray *_immutableArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_mutableArray];
```

Comment: This is probably more expensive than just using a default size and letting it expand itself.

Comment: Measure it and report back with numbers.

Comment: I think getting a conclusive result as to which is faster would be really difficult without analyzing the source code. There are so many variables like number of elements to add,memory conditions (and thus the performance of realloc), etc.

Comment: You can definitely test these claims.

Comment: How would you empirically quantify memory fragmentation (which would effect realloc speed) in such a test?

Comment: Not to be flippant, but you should already know the answer to your question, if you are positively asserting that one method is more expensive than another.

Comment: "Probably" ... It was an educated guess.